# Group multiple columns of different datatype in R

Tags: r

I have 4 columns `title`, `text`, `year`, `code`. I want to group the title by the number of texts it has received. Also, I want to uniquely group the title having the same name along with the year (int) and code (char).

For e.g.

I have

```
title | text            | year  | code
-------------------------------------
A     | I like...       | 2012  | i12
B     | I wish...       | 2012  | i12
C     | review1         | 2013  | i13
C     | review2         | 2013  | i13
C     | review3         | 2013  | i13
D     | Detecting...    | 2014  | i14
C     | review1         | 2015  | i15
C     | review2         | 2015  | i15
E     | New...          | 2016  | i16
```

What I want is:

```
title | text                     |  year | code
-----------------------------------------------
A     | I like...                |  2012 | i12
B     | I wish...                |  2012 | i12
C     | review1 review2 review3  |  2013 | i13
D     | Detecting...             |  2014 | i14
C     | review1 review2          |  2015 | i15
E     | New...                   |  2016 | i16
```

I have tried:

```
df %>%
  group_by(gp = c(0, na.omit(cumsum(lead(title) != title)))) %>% 
  summarize(title = unique(title), text = paste0(text, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  select(-gp)
```

which gives me:

```
title | text                     | 
----------------------------------
A     | I like...                |  
B     | I wish...                |  
C     | review1 review2 review3  |  
D     | Detecting...             |  
C     | review1 review2          |  
E     | New...                   |
```

But when I do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(gp = c(0, na.omit(cumsum(lead(title) != title)))) %>% 
  summarize(title = unique(title), text = paste0(text, collapse = " ")) %>% 
  select(-gp, year, code)
```

It gives:

```
Error in `stop_subscript()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `year` doesn't exist.
```

*Data*

```
df <- data.frame(title = c('A','B','C','C','C','D','C','C','E'),
                 text = c('I like...', 'I wish...', 'review1','review2','review3',
                          'Detecting...','review1','review2', 'New...'),
                 year = c(2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016),
                 code = c("i12", "i12", "i13", "i13", "i13", "i14", "i15", "i15", "i16"))
```

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: Your code after summarise doesn't have the year column or code, thus you are trying to select columns that doesn't exist.

Comment: @onyambu, I have updated the question. The second table.

Comment: whats the difference between this question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489371/group-the-column-values-uniquely-in-r/72489731#72489731)

Comment: @onyambu, This question has two extra columns.

Comment: just add those two columns to your grouping variable. or simply `df %>%
  group_by(title, year, code) %>%
  summarise(text=paste(text, collapse = ' '))`

Comment: yOU should have included them when asking your previous question. Asking half questions makes solving your questions difficult. eg. in the solution you have cumsum etc. But if you had included the two columns, the solution would have been simpler. Check the comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df %>%
    group_by(gp = c(0, na.omit(cumsum(lead(title) != title))) , year , code) %>% 
    summarize(title = unique(title), text = paste0(text, collapse = " ")) %>%
    relocate(year , code , .after = last_col()) %>%
    select(-gp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `unique` after you `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(title, year) |> 
  mutate(text = paste(text, collapse = " ")) |> 
  unique()
```